# PIN on Kubuntu lockscreen (KDE Plasma 5.27.8)

Tags: kubuntu, kde, password, lock-screen

I am new to linux and have the newest Kubuntu 23.10. I'm loving the customization options but am having a problem right now with the lock screen. I followed this (https://fostips.com/log-into-linux-pc-pin-number/) guide to get a pin on my login screen, but it doesn't aplly to the lock screen. I then tried to follow this (https://blog.fancypi.cn/blog/pin_login_in_kde.html) guide to get a pin on my lock screen, but my system doesn't have the '/etc/pam.d/kde' file.

Does the newest version of KDE use a different file to store the lock screen password?
Does anyone know how I could get this to work?

I was thinking of maybe installing kscreenlocker as it doesnt seem to be on my system by default, however it doesn't show up on the discover app and I don't know enough yet to download the repo myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/pam.d/kde` is kscreenlocker's upstream default service name. If it don't exist, you should copy `/etc/pam.d/login` for sane defaults, then edit from there.

kscreenlocker is part of the Plasma base installation, so if you have the lock screen it is definitely installed.

Comment: What do you mean by copy it for sane defaults?

Comment: To `/etc/pam.d/kde`.

Comment: Thank you! I copied '/etc/pam.d/login' and made the copied files name kde. I followed the guide I linked and all I had to do extra is create a plain text file '/etc/pam.d/kde_unlock_pin' before following the steps. Now it works. Cheers!